# Why are the values of forms not updating?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm relatively new to asp but not sure why certain values from my forms aren't updating. I have a somewhat hacky way of going about amending the url that MVC might do better, I'm open to suggestions.

When this page loads it leaves input1 and input2 blank correctly since there's no entry's in the url. When I use the button to submit it is also fine. It is when the forms are changed and the button clicked again that the values of input1 & input2 remain unchanged. Why is that?

```
 public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        int count = 0;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["entry1"] != null && Request.QueryString["entry2"] != null)
            {
                input1.Value = Request.QueryString["entry1"];
                input2.Value = Request.QueryString["entry2"];
                CompareFSUI();
            }

        }

        protected void BtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
            if(count == 0)
            {
                count++;
                Response.Redirect(url + "?" + "entry1=" + input1.Value + "&entry2=" + input2.Value);
            } else {

                //the code makes it here the second button click)

                count++;

                 //but the values of input1 & input2, though changed by the user, go back to original submission of first button click (original url w/ entry's)
                Response.Redirect(url + "?" + "entry1=" + input1.Value + "&entry2=" + input2.Value);
            }
        }

        protected void CompareFSUI()
        {
            String lasx_guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            (continues to update parts of asp placeholder from here on)
```

---

```
<input type="text" name="Input 1" id="input1" runat="server" /> 
 <input type="text" name="Input 2" id="input2" runat="server" /> 
 <asp:Button ID="Fetch" class="btn btn-secondary" runat="server" Text="Compare" OnClick="BtnClick" />
```

Comment: Use the same string for Id and name i.e. id="input1" and name="input1". Also share the form if this doesn't resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code in the if and else blocks are same. You are essentially taking the same values and redirecting back to same form again. Which makes the textboxes have the same value

**Current**

Initial stage: no values
set value and click button: redirect to same page with input values and retrieve them back into input again.

**Correct**
In pageLoad, take the values into variables instead of putting them back into textboxes. Also comparison should be inside the btnClick instead of redirecting user back to same page with same values..

Pseudo Code as follows:-

```
pageLoad
  if(!IsPostback) {
       // get from query string and populate textboxes.. Compare
       var entry1 = Request.QueryString["entry1"]; ...
       Compare()
  }

btnClick() {
   // get from textboxes 
   var entry1 = input1.Value; ....
   Compare();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            {
            if (Request.QueryString["entry1"] != null && 
             Request.QueryString["entry2"] != null)
            {
                input1.Value = Request.QueryString["entry1"];
                input2.Value = Request.QueryString["entry2"];
                CompareFSUI();
            }
           }
        }`